# ionic 2 ViewController for popTo

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to use popTo ( http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/#popTo ) in my ionic 2 application. Which requires a ViewController ( http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-beta.7/api/components/nav/ViewController/ )

I am not able to figure out how to create a page as a ViewController that is usable in popTo with the documents present over the internet.

Has someone used popTo ? any heads up !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NavController.getByIndex(int index)` returns a ViewController, so you can use: `this.navCtrl.popTo(getByIndex(index))`.

Don't forget to inject the NavControlelr properly

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

class MyComponent {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
}
```

See here for Reference: 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#getByIndex

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you please provide more information on `getByIndex(int index)`. Which module does `getByIndex` come under? Typescript dosn't recognise `getByIndex`.

Comment: `this.navCtrl.popTo( this.navCtrl.getByIndex(1));`   `getByIndex` is a method in the `NavController`

Comment: This still works and should be marked as the right answer. But should be edited to reflect kamayd's comment.

Comment: `this.navCtrl.popTo(this.navCtrl.getByIndex(index))` is what worked for me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

this.navCtrl.popTo() also works if you provide a ViewController which is how I prefer to popTo().  It's dangerous to rely on the index because you may add a page to the flow which will change the index.  This way you just give it the name of the page to pop back to.

`let popToViewController = Utilities.getViewController(this.returnPageName, this.navCtrl);
this.navCtrl.popTo(popToViewController);`

I had to create a utility method to obtain the ViewController from the NavController:

`public static getViewController(pageName: string, navController: NavController): ViewController {
    for (let viewController of navController.getViews()) {
      if (viewController.name == pageName) {
        return viewController
      }
    }
    return null;
}`

Comment: I ended up writing the exact same utility methods. The problem I am running into is that during the minification process it wipes out the `.name` values; so we cannot walk the stack looking for our page name. :(

Comment: You are right Cody, after building the ionic project with --prod --release the name property is no longer available.  I am now converting the code to pass the actual navcontroller around in nav params or globals.  If you found a better solution please let me know.